# Are there constants for PHP socket error codes?

Tags: php, sockets

I'm connecting to a remote host as follows:

```
$conn = stream_socket_client("ssl://$host:$port", $e_code, $e_string, 2, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $ctx);
```

How should I interpret the error code?

The docs say the error code "holds the system level error number that occurred in the system-level connect() call."

I can't find any PHP constants which define these error codes.

Comment: My guess is that will vary depending on the system; and your best bet will be look into the error string.

Comment: I was hoping that PHP would expose the system constants, but it doesn't look like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Connect()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/connect) defines some errors it can return, like EACCES or ECONNREFUSED. These constants correspond with [a number](http://www.ioplex.com/~miallen/errcmp.html).

Answer (score 0):

The variable `$e_string` which you are passing by reference will contain a str string equivalent of the error, if an error occurs.